# Makefile, Don't know how to make target

Tags: c++, c, makefile, solaris

I tried running the following Makefile

```
SRC=../src
INC=../inc

OBJS=$(SRC)/rrbsSimulator.o \
     $(SRC)/XMLParser.o

ALLOBJS=rrbsSimulator.o \
        XMLParser.o

CC=/usr/sfw/bin/gcc

FLAGS= -Wall -g -m64

AINC=-I$(INC)
ALLLIBS=-lcc -lsocket -lnsl -lpthread -lstdc++

%.o: %.cpp
   $(CC) $(AINC) $(FLAGS) -c $<

lcc: $(ALLOBJS)
   $(CC)  $(FLAGS) $(ALLLIBS) $(ALLOBJS) -o lycaUSSDSIM
   mv lycaUSSDSIM ../bin


clean:
   rm -f $(ALLOBJS)  ../bin/lycaUSSDSIM
```

I am getting the following error

```
make: Fatal error: Don't know how to make target `rrbsSimulator.o'
```

What is the mistake I have done?

Comment: I guess `CR (carriage return)` is there at the end of line before the error line.

Comment: Does rrbsSimulator.cpp exist at the expected location? To my experience failure to find rrbsSimulator.cpp gives this error.

Comment: Are you using spaces to indent commends, such as `$(CC) ...`, in your Makefile? If you are, change them to one Tab and try again.

Comment: Likely OBJS don't need $(SRC) as prefix. Anyway, rrbaSimulator is mentioned with two different paths, so that could couse confusion.

Comment: Or you can just get rid of The ALLOBJS var, and use OBJS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error `Don't know how to make target`rrbsSimulator.o'` means one of two things. Either

1. There is no rule that can make this file, or
2. There is a rule, but its dependencies cannot be made (or found).

This looks like a valid rule.

```
%.o: %.cpp
   $(CC) $(AINC) $(FLAGS) -c $<
```

Therefore the most likely cause is that its dependency, with the suffix of cpp, is missing. Look for `rrbsSimulator.cpp` in the relevant source folder.

Unfortunately makefiles used by some legacy versions of `make` are ridiculously picky over formatting like spaces and tabs, and it's not possible to see those in this format. If you are using one of those `make`s you need to check the whitespace carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Where do your source files situated?

Looking at `SRC` and `OBJS` variables I can imagine that your source code files are placed in ../src folder. But `%.o : %.cpp` will search for both *.o and *.cpp files in the current directory. Thus it would not find neither rrbsSimulator.o nor rrbsSimulator.cpp.

Btw, why don't you use a standard `CFLAGS` variable instead of yourown `FLAGS`?
and you better write it this way:

```
FLAGS += -Wall -g -m64
```

What if you would like to add some extra flags from command line later on? This will let you call your makefile in this way:

```
make FLAGS=-s
```

Answer (score 1):

Add VPATH = $(SRC) it will work. Also need to concentrate with spacing when we implementing Makefile.

Answer (score 0):

rrbsSimulator.cpp does not exist.